# How to protect privacy(from the w command) on shared linux machines?

Tags: unix, privacy, obfuscate

In my workplace, we have shared Linux machines to which all employees log on to do their work. However, a simple 'w' command gives me a list of who's logged in and what they're doing. The same applies for me when others use the 'w' command (even non-admin users can see it).

However, I'd like to maintain some privacy and not let others know what command I'm running currently. Is there some way I could achieve this obfuscation/privacy in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persuade the administrator that this is an issue and that they should apply a solution such as [grsecurity or SELinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11873/i-dont-want-other-users-see-my-processes-in-ps-aux-i-have-root-its-debian-h)

or

Make local copies of the commands and rename them.

Comment: Is there nothing that may be done at the my end? Getting the admin to make any changes can be a problem. :(

Comment: @Mindstorm: See update

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be done by the sys admin. Depending on what you are trying to hide, users can also see the processes you are running using the 'ps -ef' command.